# Use Browser Back Button For Navigation in a Scrollable Element

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Here's the scenario: I have an element with a scrollbar. The user clicks a link that takes them to a bookmark inside this element, which causes the element to scroll.

Afterwards when the user wants to return to the original scroll position, the natural thing for them to do is to click the browser's Back button.

Interestingly, the browser's address bar does update to reflect the initial navigation within the element as well as the click of the back button. However, clicking the back button does not result in the desired scroll. This makes sense.

So, is there a way using straight javascript (no third party libraries) to achieve this? Below is a complete sample, with a link at the bottom of the div. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<style>
    div {
        height:400px;

        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    span {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        width: 600px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <span id="first">
        First: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Neque gravida in fermentum et. Magna sit amet purus gravida. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus.
    </span>
    <span id="second">
        Second: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Neque gravida in fermentum et. Magna sit amet purus gravida. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus.
    </span>
    <span id="third">
        Third: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Neque gravida in fermentum et. Magna sit amet purus gravida. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus.
    </span>
    <span id="forth">
        Forth: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Neque gravida in fermentum et. Magna sit amet purus gravida. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus.
    </span>
    <a href="#first">Click to go to first paragraph, then click the browser Back button to return here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user click to link with id or browser back button the url changes. So you can handle this event with:

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function (event) {
    // The URL changed...
});
```

Then you have `event.newURL` and `event.oldURL`. With that you can do what ever you want.